# How to get the text of several td which have same id name?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have table in that 
five td which contain same id. Id="divParent" but in that different text,
i want to  access all the text in array which id  ="divParent" in other page using java script.
how to get this
i tried to do this using this code;

```
var divParent=new Array();
       divParent=window.parent.document.getElementById('divParent');
```

Answer (score 4):

The `id` attribute should be unique across a single document. That is to say, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. You might be better served using the `class` attribute and `document.getElementsByClassName('divParent')`

Answer (score 2):

You should never have same id repeat on the same page. Change it to class and access elements by class instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through each td

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique. But if you want to loop through table cells and put them into an array:

```
    var divParent=new Array();
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var t=0;t<td.length;t++){
        if(td[t].className == "table_cell_class"){
            divParent.push(td[t].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

the innerHTML gets everything that's inside the table cell element.